# mclapply encountered error in user code

Tags: r, apply, lapply, mapply

**When I run mclapply:**

```
> ListofCSVs<- mclapply(list.files(pattern = "2013"), function(n){
    read.table(n, header=TRUE, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )}
  ,mc.cores=12)
```

Where list.files(pattern = "2013") lists 12 CSV files:

```
> list.files(pattern = "2013")
 [1] "BONDS 2013 01.csv" "BONDS 2013 02.csv" "BONDS 2013 03.csv" "BONDS 2013 04.csv" "BONDS 2013 05.csv" "BONDS 2013 06.csv" "BONDS 2013 07.csv"
 [8] "BONDS 2013 08.csv" "BONDS 2013 09.csv" "BONDS 2013 10.csv" "BONDS 2013 11.csv" "BONDS 2013 12.csv"
```

**I get:**

```
Warning message:
In mclapply(list.files(pattern = ".csv"), function(n) { :
  **scheduled core 2, 1 encountered error** in user code, all values of the job will be affected.
```

> print(ListofCSVs[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330274/an-error-in-one-job-contaminates-others-with-mclapply)])
>   ....."fatal error in wrapper code"

**I have tried** [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330274/an-error-in-one-job-contaminates-others-with-mclapply) , but my data is still not loading correctly.

[This](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/variancePartition/inst/doc/variancePartition.pdf) says that it may be a problem of too many threads....

**I can load the files correctly with lapply.**

**I have also checked that each read.table works**, hence, I do not think it is a data issue.

```
ai<-read.table("BONDS 2013 i.csv", header=TRUE, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Each CSV is about 1G with 40 Columns.

I also use foreach %dopar% and it works.

I have run the same code with two cores. It doesnt work.

I have run it with one core and it works.

The data is in the working directory

Thanks!

I have 16 cores and 122 GB (Amazon Cloud AWS - Linux)

UPDATE: This works...

```
> ListofCSVs<- parLapply(cl, list.files(pattern = ".csv"), function(n){
 read.table(n, header=TRUE, sep=',',stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
   })
```

go figure....

Comment: If you want to speed up reading data into R: Before parallelising have a look at `data.table::fread` and `readr::read_csv`. They might solve the problem. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes-in-r/1728422#1728422

Comment: your read.table() has an extra "," too! after stringsAsFactors

Comment: The extra comma does not matter. I made some toy files and ran the same code. It worked correctly on my laptop.

Comment: Consider using explicit paths to files.

Comment: Just to confirm: you _are_ using a *nix OS, yes?

Comment: Thanks! I am in aws (amazon cloud... redhat)

Comment: I tried fread and got this error:[1] "try-error"

attr(,"condition")

<simpleError in fread(n, header = TRUE, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE): mmap'd region has EOF at the end>