# Obtain coda files from runjags when I know that some simulations fail

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mcmc, runjags

I am splitting my dataset by simulation ID and applying a runjags function simultaneously to each of these subdatasets. This allows me to take advantage of parallel processing and run my simulation on a cluster. A job that takes over 1 day can be completed in around 2 hours.

Out of the 1000 simulations I'm running, around 25 fail. I am using a for loop with a trap catch error to extract the coda files from the simulations that ran successfully. The problem is that once a simulation fails, the error affects all of the cores that I am using, and I can't extract the coda files for the simulations that ran successfully as well.

Any suggestions? I am including code and log files below. Thank you.

```
library(parallel)
library(coda)

#1) using mclapply to apply a function to all simulations simultaneously

output_models <- parallel::mclapply(subsetdata, function(x){
  library(runjags)
  set.seed(1)
  model_data = x
 
  
  runJagsOut <- run.jags(method = "simple",
                         model = "tempModel.txt",
                         monitor = c( "mu" ),
                         data = model_data,
                         #inits = initsList, # NOTE: Let JAGS initialize.
                         n.chains = 1, # NOTE: Not only 1 chain.
                         adapt = 500,
                         burnin = 3000,
                         sample = 2500,
                         thin = 1,
                         summarise = TRUE,
                         plots = FALSE)
  return(runJagsOut)
  
}, mc.cores = numcores)


#2) Build an empty list vector

mcmc <- list()

#3) Extracting coda files for each of the simulations. tryCatch function in place to 'ignore' simulations that fail

for (SimulID in 1:length(unique(df$SimulID))) {
  tryCatch({
  mcmc[[SimulID]] <- cbind(output_models[[SimulID]][["mcmc"]][[1]],SimulID)
  }, error=function(e){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})
}

#4) Main text file with the coda for each simulation

lapply(mcmc, function(x) write.table( data.frame(x), 'output.txt'  , append= T, sep=',', col.names = FALSE ))
```

This is what I see from the log file after the job completes on the cluster. The 1000th simulation followed by an error, followed by the subscript being out of bounds error for the for loop.

```
. Initializing model
. Adapting 500
-------------------------------------------------| 500
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ 100%
Adaptation successful
. Updating 3000
-------------------------------------------------| 3000
************************************************** 100%
. . Updating 2500
-------------------------------------------------| 2500
************************************************** 100%
. . . . Updating 0
. Deleting model
. 
Simulation complete.  Reading coda files...
Coda files loaded successfully
Calculating summary statistics...
Finished running the simulation
Warning message:
In parallel::mclapply(subsetdata, function(x) { :
  scheduled cores 39, 24, 35, 21, 22, 23, 29, 3, 8, 19, 47, 34, 6, 48, 10, 33, 38, 41, 31, 18, 5, 16, 37 encountered errors in user code, all values of the jobs will be affected
ERROR : subscript out of bounds 
ERROR : subscript out of bounds 
ERROR : subscript out of bounds
```

Comment: Suggestion: If you replace `output_models < parallel::mclapply(..., mc.cores = numcores)` with `future::plan("multicore", workers = numcores)` and `output_models <- future.apply::future_lapply(...)`, I think you'll get some more informative error messages, which help you narrow in on what's failing.

Comment: Thank you for this. The lapply functions works on my computer whenever I'm running RStudio, but for some reason, it doesn't work on the cluster. The only reason I can think of is that the cluster runs on a Linux environment. I tried it out and the code was stuck in one place for around 30 minutes.

Comment: I want to add that parLapply also does not work on the cluster.

Comment: Note that `plan(multicore)` uses the same `mclapply()` machinery internally,. So, if one works, then the other does too.  The reason why I mentioned `future_lapply()` w/ `plan(multicore)` is that it most likely will give you more information/clues - than just "scheduled cores 39, 24, ... 37 encountered errors in user code, all values of the jobs will be affected".

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply. I found this page and was able to make the code work by adding mc.preschedule = FALSE to the end of my function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330274/an-error-in-one-job-contaminates-others-with-mclapply